# Routing Issue - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have pages that are generated from a database, based on the URI. Functons as it should, however I can't set-up my `routes` to eliminate the controller and function from the URL.

```
$route['studios/(:any)'] = 'studios/location/$1';
```

Right now, I have the route to show the controller name and the URI variable (whatever that may be). However, I want to eliminate the controller name as well and just display the URI variable that's called as the URL. Hard to explain - hopefully someone picks up my drift...

Current URL would be: `domain.com/studios/studio1`

But I want to just display: `domain.com/studio1`

I tried `$route['/(:any)'] = 'studios/location/$1';`, but that's messing up my entire site.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$route['studios(/:any)*'] = 'studios/location';
```

This route will force everything from `studios` on to `studios/location`. You can then access any of the parameters using URI segments:

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

If your URL was `somewhere.com/studios/location/2`, `$id` would resolve to `2`

However, since you want it to just be from the root on, you will have to put your override route at the bottom of the routes file so it is assessed last:

```
// all other routes here. Which must be specifically 
// defined if you want a catch all like the one you mentioned
$route['(:any)'] = 'studios/location';
```

Alternatively, if you want a high maintenance site, you can specify a collection of routes like so:

```
$route['(studio1|studio2|studio3)'] = 'studios/location/$1';
```

Answer (score 0):

how is it "messing up your site"?

In any case, you should not have the / before (:any)

Just:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'studios/location/$1';
```

EDIT:

BEFORE the $route['(:any)'], you'll need to specify routes fro all your controllers; this is pretty normal, don't know if I'd call it "high maintenance", but you'll need to decide

Comment: probably cause that route forces every request to studios/location

Comment: that's what OP says he wants; ah, I see what you mean. That explains "messes up my entire site". I'll edit above

Comment: Yeah, the only reason it would be considered high maintenance is because by default CI will access by controller/method/parameters and when there's a catch all it pretty much hijacks that. You'd need to specify a route for all pages above the catch all and if you for some reason have an ever changing site or hand it off to someone else they have to know about that.